# How to define type for a specific field in ElasticSearch for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am struggling with elasticsearch-rails.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "listings" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "listing" : {
        "properties" : {
          "address" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "authorized" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "categories" : {
            "properties" : {
              "created_at" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "parent_id" : {
                "type" : "long"
              },
              "updated_at" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "url_name" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "cid" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "city" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "country" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "created_at" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "featured" : {
            "type" : "boolean"
          },
          "geojson" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "latitude" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "longitude" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "phone" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "postal" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "province" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "thumbnail_filename" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "updated_at" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          },
          "url" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to change the type for the geojson field from `string` to `geo_point` so I can use the geo_shape query on it.

I tried this in my model:

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :geojson, type: 'geo_shape'
    end
  end
```

with peculiar results. When I queried the mapping with `$ curl 'localhost:9200/_all/_mapping?pretty'`, the geojson field still shows as `type: string`.

Within a Rails console, if I do `Listing.mappings.to_hash`, it seems to show that the `geojson` field is of type `geo_shape`.

And yet when running this query:

```
Listing.search(query: { fuzzy_like_this: { fields: [:name], like_text: "gap" } }, query: { fuzzy_like_this_field: { city: { like_text: "San Francisco" } } }, query: { geo_shape: { geojson: { shape: { type: :envelope, coordinates: [[37, -122],[38,-123]] } } } }); response.results.total; response.results.map { |r| puts "#{r._score} | #{r.name}, #{r.city} (lat: #{r.latitude}, lon: #{r.longitude})" }
```

ES complains that the `geojson` field is not of type `geo_shape`.

What am I missing? How do I tell ES that I want the `geojson` field to be of type `geo_shape` and not `string`?

Comment: Did you recreate the index with your new mapping using something like: `rake elasticsearch:import:model CLASS=Listing FORCE=y`?

Comment: That was the issue, I didn't delete and recreate the mapping. In the rails console, I ran `Model.__elasticsearch__.delete_index!` and then `Model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` followed by `Model.import`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't delete and recreate the mapping.

In the rails console, I ran `Model.__elasticsearch__.delete_index!` and then `Model.__elasticsearch__.create_index!` followed by `Model.import`